# How to pass props in the url in react js?

Tags: reactjs, url, react-props, send

I want to know the correct format on how we can send the props in the url in react js.

Let say my prop name is "isOpen" which is of type boolean.

And my url is `http://localhost:3000/Home`.

Now with this url I want to send my prop as well. How it can be done?

I have tried something like this `http://localhost:3000/Home/isOpen/false` but it is throwing this error in the console.

> Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/Home/bundle.dev.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

you can use query string in URL, in your case it should be like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/Home/?isOpen=false
```

and read `isOpen` from URL with use of `URLSearchParams` and `useLocation` hook:

```
const location = useLocation();
const isOpen = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get("isOpen");
```